# C# MVC dynamic Route based on config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing

Is it possible to have a dynamic route name so that route name can be read from a config file?

e.g. where someStringReadFromConfig would be populated from a config file.

```
[Route("api/v1/test/"+ someStringReadFromConfig +")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public TestController()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 **You can simply add **`routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`
```

add you code

```
[Route("api/v1/test/"+ someStringReadFromConfig +")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
public TestController()
{
}
}
```